# Can we execute DWLoader.exe to load datatable into PDW database using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Can we use DWLoader.exe (in C#) to load datatable into PDW database ?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I could not find a way to try that :(. Ddint see any example.

Comment: I tried to use SQL Bulk Copy into PDW, but it seems PDW wont support it.